# meteor.js - how to check values from asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, callback

**CONTEXT**

Im making a call which, if successful, changes the value of a boolean from false to true. Then, outside of this call, I check if this boolean is true and, if so, I route to another page.

**PROBLEM**

Console logs indicate that the if statement which checks the boolean's value is being executed before the calls have had a time to change the boolean's value. I realize that this is because of asynchronicity, but not sure what the correct design pattern for this would be. Here is a snippet:

```
     //set variables to check if the even and user get updated or if error
    var eventUpdated = false;

     Meteor.call('updateEvent', eventId, eventParams, function(error, result){
      if(error){
        toastr.error(error.reason)
      } else {
        var venueId = result;
        toastr.success('Event Info Updated');  
        eventUpdated = true;

        console.log(eventUpdated)
      }               
    });

    console.log(eventUpdated)


     if (eventUpdated) {
         Router.go('/get-started/confirmation');
     }
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

I'm guessing I need a way to hold the if statement from being executed until the callback returns a value. Based on Googling, I think this has something to do with [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) but not too clear on how to actually use it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't move the code block that is outside of the Meteor.call('updateEvent') callback into the callback? You can use something like wrapAsync, or use session variables as suggested below, but why not just put it into the callback?

Comment: Actually there is... the reason is that I actually have three callback functions and the `if` statement checks if all three are true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the conditional is run before the callbacks have returned a value, you need a conditional that is inside a function that is being run reactively. I used the following code:

```
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
        if (Session.get('userUpdated') && Session.get('passwordUpdated') && Session.get('eventUpdated')) {
            Router.go('/get-started/confirmation');
        }
    });
```

You can read more about Meteor reactivity [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The issue is that since it's an async function, this:

```
console.log(eventUpdated)


     if (eventUpdated) {
         Router.go('/get-started/confirmation');
     }
```

Runs before the actual call. Use a Session.set inside the call like this:

```
Session.set("eventUpdated", "true");
```

And then outside:

```
eventUpdated = Session.get("eventUpdated");

console.log(eventUpdated)


     if (eventUpdated) {
         Router.go('/get-started/confirmation');
     }
```

Since Session is a reactive variable you should get the current value correctly.

Comment: This actually did not work, not sure why. I also tried putting the `Session.get` directly inside the `if` conditions (since maybe the session get is reactive but the variable that it's put into is not)... this still did not work. See my answer for what actually worked.